# What video editing software allows for easy alignment of visual transitions with the soundtrack?

Tags: sync, music

When editing video projects, I always try to align the transitions between cuts with the music. The timing of how fast the transitions happen and exactly when they appear should often be made to correspond with certain points in the music. Is there any software which allows for transitions to be “snapped” in place to key parts of the music, either manually or automatically, or otherwise provides a useful interface for adjusting the visual transitions to match the music?

I use OS X.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any editor that do this natively, but there are plugins such as the RedGiant's [Trapcode Sound-Keys (it has a free trial so you can check it out first)](http://www.redgiantsoftware.com/products/all/trapcode-sound-keys/) which allow you to this is a fairly easy manner.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2265?viewlocale=en_US) is a complete tutorial on how to make it using iMovie '11

Answer (score 2):

Snap to beats works very good, but sometimes you may want more control, use the waveforms of the audio channel to see where the beats are, then this should be fairly easy and fully controllable